# Switching to superuser mode in vim session

Tags: vim, vi

After opening a file created by root in `vim`, how to change the current user to superuser mode without quitting or before saving?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This should do the trick.

> :w !sudo tee %

More tricks like that here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Su-write

Comment: :w stands for write
the sudo tree command will spawn a tee process with superuser permissions
the tee process redirect the standard input to both standard output and the file, which is given by %

Also: nice trick.

Comment: The only downside with that short version is that it will output the file to the screen while saving, you can remedy that by adding > /dev/null to the end of the command. But it's easier to write like that and i don't mind the extra output.

Comment: Now it asks for the super user password and when i enter the password it says incorrect password.But the password entered is right..

Comment: Sudo asks for the current user password. You also need to enable sudo usage with visudo if your distribution doesn't configure it properly for you.

you can test your sudo setup with the command "sudo -l" which will list the commands you are allowed to run. If it fails or doesn't report any commands, you need to edit sudo configuration.